# Add new column with % in R

Tags: r, group-by

I Have Attrition dataset where I'm focusing on two fields rightnow, department and Status(Terminated or not). Now I want to make new column which will have percentage of people terminated from that specific department.
I'm not able to add that in original dataset but I was able to create dataset with % termination by department by this.

```
dept <- data %>% group_by(dept, STATUS) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% mutate(percent = count/sum(count) * 100)
```

Which returned dept, count and percent of termination.

```
dept status count percent
 A      Y    80     63..
 A      N    46     36...
 B      Y    30     20..
 .      .    .       .
 .      .    .       .
```

Now I just want to add percent column of Status Y in original dataset respective to dept.

Edit:
original data:

```
id  job_sat   dept   eth  status
 1     2       A      As    N
 2     1       C      Bl    Y
 .     .       .      .     .
 .     .       .      .     .
```

Expected Output:

```
id  job_sat   dept   eth  status dept_per
 1     2       A      As    N      63..
 2     1       C      Bl    Y      59..
 .     .       .      .     .
 .     .       .      .     .
```

Comment: Do you want to have the percent against Y alone, keeping NA against N?

Comment: Please share reproducible data

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Please check the updated ques

Comment: @Mohanasundaram please see my original dataset in which I want to add new column which will have %Y of that dept

Comment: @RonakShah Hi ronak, I was able to solve that one on my own, that's why deleted that ques. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the percentage of `status == 'Y'` in each department by :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%  group_by(dept) %>% mutate(dept_per = mean(status == 'Y') * 100)
```

which is similar to :

```
data %>% group_by(dept) %>% mutate(dept_per = sum(status == 'Y')/n() * 100)
```

---

This can also be done in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, dept_per := mean(status == 'Y'), dept]
```

and base R :

```
data$dept_per <- with(data, ave(status == 'Y', dept))
```

Comment: I'm just getting 0 in the new column

Comment: are you sure you have exact "Y" in the `status` column and nothing else? No whitespace or no lower case "y" ? Can you update your post with `dput(head(data))` ?

Comment: OMG got it! Thank you so much! You're genius :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

originaldf$dept_per <- with(deptdf[deptdf$status=="Y",], count[match(originaldf$dept, dept)])

Comment: Hey, what is deptdf here? Newly created dataframe?

Comment: deptdf is the data frame which as the percent